# How to automate git tasks that require a commit message?

Tags: vim, git, tcsh

I'm writing a script to automate a Git task. Doing this manually, there are a few points where git opens vim to edit a commit message, and I have to type `:wq`. Is there a way to pre-send these keystrokes from my script, but only if vim opens? Alternatively, is there a way to avoid opening vim in the first place?

I'm using tcsh.

Comment: And what Git task, exactly, is it?

Comment: @DanielB `git subtree pull --prefix foo/bar/path repo branch --squash`

Comment: Have you tried using `git subtree`'s `--message=` (or `-m`) option to provide a commit message ahead of time? That should avoid opening up vim in the first place.

Comment: @8bittree Good idea. It's preferable that I retain the auto-generated message, but I'm sure I can work out some hackery to derive it, if there's nothing simpler.

Comment: @8bittree Perfect!

Comment: I've edited your question (pending approval) to focus more on your actual problem, rather than the one specific potential solution. Feel free to reject my edit or roll it back if you disagree with my changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just avoid opening Vim in the first place.

One option for that is to make use of the `--message=<message>` (or `-m <message>`, for short) option to `git subtree pull`. The downside is that you can't use the default message provided by git and instead have to come up with your own. The upside is that this should work just about anywhere that git needs a commit message.

Another option which *does* use the default message is to change the "editor" that git opens to cat. Just remember to change it back immediately after:

```
git config --local core.editor /path/to/cat
git subtree pull --prefix foo/bar/path repo branch --squash
git config --local core.editor /path/to/vim-or-other-editor
```

The upside to this is that you can use the default message provided by git. The downside is that this won't work if the default commit message is empty, as is typical when doing a plain `git commit`.